# react-spring animation only working on click, not on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-spring, react-three-fiber

I have a basic rotating cube I've made with react-three-fiber, and `onPointerOver` (also tried `onPointerEnter`) I want to smoothly rotate it to its starting position via `useSpring`. However, not only does it not do so when I hover, but it will only do so `onClick`. I have a totally different function that executes `onClick` -- and if I disabled that prop then the rotation reset fails altogether.

I've got a pretty simple set up in my `Box` component:

```
export const Box = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const boxRef = useRef<Mesh>();

  const starterRotation = [0, 1, 1];

  useFrame(() => {
    if (boxRef.current) {
      boxRef.current.rotation.x += 0.01;
      boxRef.current.rotation.y -= 0.01;
    }
  });

  const [resetRotation, setSpring] = useSpring(() => ({
    rotation: starterRotation
  })); // trying to use the `set` syntax to call the useSpring and smoothly animate to a certain rotation.
  const springs = useSpring({ scale: active ? 1.5 : 1, config: config.wobbly });

  return (
    <animated.mesh
      // @ts-ignore
      rotation={resetRotation.rotation}
      scale={springs.scale}
      onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
      onPointerOver={() => setSpring.start()}
      ref={boxRef}
    >
      <boxGeometry args={[2, 1, 2]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color="royalblue" />
    </animated.mesh>
  );
};
```

Here's a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-rotating-cube-np4v6

From what I can tell in their [docs](https://react-spring.io/hooks/use-spring) this is the correct way. I also saw some github issues discussions on it, and there seemed to be some concern about the second argument of the `useSpring` deconstruction not working properly, but the rotation works for me -- it's jut the triggering event that won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work, the issue is you're still updating the `rotation` based on the ref in a `useFrame` call so that's updated every frame. Which will override the animation value.

The second issue is that if you stoped the `useFrame` from animating `rotation` it won't work because the spring's internal value will be set to `[0,1,1]` but that's what you want it to animate to.

This is a good opportunity to use `from` and `to` props of `useSpring`, what I would do is use a ref to stop the `useFrame` animation and then use the ref to get the current values of the rotation to use as `from` in the `springSet.start` function and then `to` which is the `starterRotation` value you've declared.

You can see this in effect here – https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-rotating-cube-forked-1j02g?file=/src/components/Box.tsx

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you 